# Newer eclipse won't X11 Forward

Tags: windows, eclipse, ubuntu, x11-forwarding

When I run Eclipse 2023-3 through ssh, the IDE pops up on the remote computer.

I use putty and Cygwin X11 on Windows to run eclipse CDT on all kinds of other OS's.
I just built a jammy jellyfish Ubuntu 22 LTS and installed Eclipse 2023-3. Everything seem OK.
If I log in through SSH to Linux and type xeyes, I get the eyes on my Windows desktop. That works.
If I run /opt/eclipse/eclipse, the IDE shows up on the Ubuntu desktop.
Is there something that has changed with jre or eclipse that re-directs back to the local display?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behavior on UBuntu 23 LTS and Eclipse 2023-06 :'(

EDIT: Ok I found a work arround with putty : In the settings Connection->SSH->X11 inside the field named "X display location" fill it with localhost:0

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tro9h.png)

Answer (score 0):

Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0) and up of Eclipse are working for me now.